# How to migrate the SharePoint solution to online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have an existing SharePoint solution with site columns, content types, webpart, timer job, svc files, list definitions, list instances, event handlers, user controls & feature to deploy pages, layouts, themes,master pages.

Is there a place where I can find the mappings to migrate the existing solution to SharePoint online?

Answer (score 3):

as seen from the question asked i believe there are lot of custom components that needs to be deployed to your sharepoint online environment.

here is what i can suggest you from the customization point of view

Timerjobs- replace with Azure web jobs

Event Handler- replace with Remote event recievers with azure environment for web app hosting

Master Page- microsoft does not recommend developers to customize the master pages in the sharepoint online environment. suggestion would be to create Custom Actions to run on your online site with customizations required.

Any Custom web part should be replaced with an sharepoint hosted addin or with PowerApps with MS Flow.

for migration of data

you can try using [METALOGIX Content migrator](https://www.quest.com/solutions/sharepoint/)

Comment: Good answer, but I would recommend SharePoint Framework Spfx web parts as the first option to replace web parts.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have your site on Sharepoint on Prem. You can use a tool like Sharegate to migrate your structure or data to SharePoint online.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint online has very different development model. in SP Online you no longer can have server side code, everything will need to be rewritten using client side javascript. Event handlers will need to be rewritten to remote event handlers and you will need some machine to handle it. For list definition have a look at pnp remote provisioning

Have a look at following resources:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/transform-farm-solutions-to-the-sharepoint-app-model

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/pnp-remote-provisioning